# intel intrinsics - function pointers to load/store

Tags: c, function-pointers, intel, intrinsics

Can I define a function pointer for `_mm_load_ps`, `_mm_store_ps` and the like?

I'm thinking about something like

```
float* x0; //param
...
__m128 (*load_x0)(float const *mem);
if((unsigned long)x0 & 15) load_x0 = &_mm_loadu_ps;
else load_x0 = &_mm_load_ps;
```

but that leads to

> undefined reference to `_mm_load_ps`
>
> undefined reference to `_mm_loadu_ps`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intrinsic functions are compiled directly into the instructions they stand for. No function calls are emitted and no implementation of these functions exist in any library. For this reason, you cannot use an intrinsic as a function pointer.

Consider making wrappers like these:

```
__m128 my_mm_load_ps(float const *mem)
{
    return _mm_load_ps(mem);
}

__m128 my_mm_loadu_ps(float const *mem)
{
    return _mm_loadu_ps(mem);
}
```

You can use the wrappers as function pointers:

```
__m128 (*load_x0)(float const *mem);
if((unsigned long)x0 & 15) load_x0 = &my_mm_loadu_ps;
else load_x0 = &my_mm_load_ps;
```

Comment: Interesting. So I gain from using the aligned load when possible but need to pay an overhead for an extra function call. You think that will pay off?

Comment: @User1291 No, it won't. There is no difference between aligned and unaligned instructions (when used on aligned data) on all but a few very old microarchitectures.

Comment: @User1291 Just use unaligned loads for everything and it's going to be fine. Benchmark when in doubt.

Answer (score -1):

are you including the header files for these functions?

"xmmintrin.h" is the appropriate header for these vector loads

Comment: Of course. (Well, using pmmintrin.h, actually.) I delete the assignments to ``load_x0`` and stubbornly use ``_mm_loadu_ps`` everywhere, there is no such error.

Comment: If these are compiler intrinsics, then they have no address and you can't a reference to them.

Comment: And I don't suppose there's a way to circumvent that restriction, no? That's ... unsatisfying. Anyway, thanks. You want to elaborate so I can accept it as an answer?

Comment: Downvoted because the answer does not answer the question.